# PDO type of arrays and how they work

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I try to learn php pdo. I am reading a tutorial.

```
$smt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = :id");
$smt->bindValue(':id', 1);
$smt->execute();
$row = $smt->fetch();
```

They say that $row gives an associative array. I search for associative arrays and I expect that if I print_r($row); I will have this:

```
Array (0 => 1, 1 => Column1Row1, 2 => Column2Row1);
```

But instead I have this:

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [0] => 1 [Column1] => Column1Row1 [1] => Column1Row1 [Column2] => Column2Row1 [2] => Column2Row1 )
```

What is this? what should I search to learn and understand how it works? I would appreciate any simple explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on how you return the PDO object. Its called a fetch style and is an input to the fetch method. You can return it in multiple ways

You can get the first object if you do

```
$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

It will return columns as numbers

You get the second if you fetch as associative array

```
$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This also happens to be the default

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be getting both the associative and indexed values. This behavior is controlled by the `PDO::FETCH_*` constants. This is the default behavior.

[`PDOStatement::fetch()` documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php):

> `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC:` returns an array indexed by column name as returned in your result set
>
> `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` (default): returns an array indexed by both column name and 0-indexed column number as returned in your result set
>
> `PDO::FETCH_BOUND`: returns `TRUE` and assigns the values of the columns in your result set to the PHP variables to which they were bound with the `PDOStatement::bindColumn()` method
>
> `PDO::FETCH_CLASS`: returns a new instance of the requested class, mapping the columns of the result set to named properties in the class. If fetch_style includes `PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE` (e.g. `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` | `PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE`) then the name of the class is determined from a value of the first column.
>
> `PDO::FETCH_INTO`: updates an existing instance of the requested class, mapping the columns of the result set to named properties in the class
>
> `PDO::FETCH_LAZY`: combines `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` and `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`, creating the object variable names as they are accessed
>
> `PDO::FETCH_NAMED`: returns an array with the same form as `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`, except that if there are multiple columns with the same name, the value referred to by that key will be an array of all the values in the row that had that column name
>
> `PDO::FETCH_NUM`: returns an array indexed by column number as returned in your result set, starting at column 0
>
> `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`: returns an anonymous object with property names that correspond to the column names returned in your result set

So what you want to do is use one of these constants like so:

```
$smt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = :id");
$smt->bindValue(':id', 1);
$smt->execute();
$row = $smt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

You can also set the default fetch mode like this:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$smt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = :id");
$smt->bindValue(':id', 1);
$smt->execute();
$row = $smt->fetch();
```